# Bootstrap modal vertical centering issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this jQuery function to vertical center modals.

```
var centeredModal = function() {
    var modalVerticalCenterClass = ".modal";

    function centerModals($element) {
        var $modals;
        if ($element.length) {
            $modals = $element;
        } else {
            $modals = jQuery(modalVerticalCenterClass + ':visible');
        }
        $modals.each(function(i) {
            var $clone = jQuery(this).clone().css('display', 'inline-block').appendTo('body');
            var top = Math.round(($clone.height() - $clone.find('.modal-content').height()) / 2);
            top = top > 0 ? top : 0;
            $clone.remove();
            jQuery(this).find('.modal-content').css({"margin-top": top, "transition" : "all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s"});
        });
    }
    jQuery(modalVerticalCenterClass).on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        centerModals(jQuery(this));
    });
    jQuery(window).on('resize', centerModals);

};
```

This function works, but some times doesn't.
If i close and then open a modal multiple times, the modal is not centered correctly.
The problem can be  '$clone.find('.modal-content').height()'?
How can i fix it?

Comment: Why not use CSS for centering..?

Comment: I need it for a project with jquery

Comment: Using jQuery for something that can be done better with something else might not be the best idea to present a jQuery project .__.

Answer (score 0):

Without using jQuery, you can simply use `display: table` for the main content container together with `margin: auto`. These rules center the modal (div or whatever) inside the page not worring about the height that may be dynamic.

After that, you can use `display: table-row` for each section of your modal (modal-header, modal-body, modal-footer) or a single `display: table-cell` for the inner container. However this second step can be omitted, I prefer to use it to maintain the (display) table consistency.

A working example of this [centered modal is here](https://jsfiddle.net/ferie/yd2Ls1sa/).

As previously said, with this solution, your modal is always centered in the page regardless its height: you can easily play with it by deleting some paragraph of the example and Re-run the fiddle.

Basically, these are the important rules:

```
.modal-content {
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 60%; /* here you can also use a fixed width */
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

For sure, you need some sort of JavaScript (jQuery or wathever) to trigger the modal opening and closing. At this point, I suggest also to use it to add a class to the `body` that prevents the page underneath the modal to scroll when this is open.